# IDA Dump Memory

Tags: ida, python

I am learning how to use IDC Scripting,or IDAPython in IDA for Reversing binary.One day i face this problem:

You are given an array of random integer(4-byte integer) lies within the memory .The random number only be calculated while debugging .

The task is : extract each of those 4-byte integer from that array and put them into a new array,print the new array on console.

Arcording to what i have learned,IDA Hex-view present only 1 Hex Number in memory for each address.

For Example : at address 00791A00 contains an integer 1134,00791A04 contains an iteger 4567.In Hex-view it will be like this

```
                     00791A00 : 34
                     00791A01 : 11
                     00791A02 : 00
                     00791A03 : 00
                     00791A04 : 67
                     00791A05 : 45
                     00791A06 : 00
                     00791A07 : 00
```

Assuming the new array named "arr". So arr[0] = 0x1134,arr[1] = 0x4567. That's what i want!
So,i'm wondering how can i do that with IDAPython,or IDC?
The only thing i have known so far about IDC or IDAPython is writing a script to dump memory to a file.

Here is the Link from where i learned to dump memory: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42744445/how-in-ida-can-save-memory-dump-with-command-or-script

I would appreciate if someone could give me a hint or walk me through with basic ideas on how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from what i remember Ida would either show  bytes with db prefix in Ida-view
or as a group of 16 bytes in hex-view
I am not sure where you see a display like that

[image]

if you mean the Ida View press d two times will make the db (define byte ) prefix to 
dd (define dword)
and selecting one dd will highlight the corresponding dword in hex view as in pic below

[image]

You can make an array using MakeDword(),MakeArray() idc commands

[image]

if you want to print the dwords with address you can employ a script like this

```
auto i;
for(i =0; i<5 ; i++) {
Message("%08x\t:%08x\n",(ScreenEA() + (i*4))Dword(ScreenEA() +(i*4)));
}
```

[image]